# html div: opaque, but allowing click to reach element behind

Tags: html, onclick

I want to make a flicking div (alternating display:none) in front (z order) of an element, but if the user clicks the element in the exact moment the div is appearing, the div receives the click, not the element.

How can I make the div transparent to clicks? That is, can it ignore the clicks so that the onclick event always goes to the element behind the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pointer-events: none;`:

```css
div {width: 150px; height: 150px; background: #eee; position: relative; margin: 0}
div:hover {border: 1px solid black}
#over {width:50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; background: red; top: 55px; left: 55px; pointer-events: none}
```

```html
<div onclick="alert('click caught')"></div>
<div id="over"></div>
```

Comment: never knew css could do that!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add to style of the overlaying div this div following code:

```
pointer-events: none;
```